# the simplest jeditable example does not work on my page

Tags: jquery, jeditable

Sorry I think I have a stupid mistake somewhere but I spend 2hours on this now... arg. I just want to try out jeditable on my website, so I included the following in my header

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"
    src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.edit').editable('whereever');
    });
    </script>
```

I have the jeditable.js file in a folder called js amongs my templates
Now I include

```
<div class="edit" id="div_1">Edit me</div>
```

in my site (body) and nothing happens

I am also loading jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com
/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">  
</script>
```

what am I doing wrong?
f

further test:
As suggested I modified the jquery statement to

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("hello!");
        $('.edit').editable('whereever');
    });
    </script>
```

but the hello output never appears in the console...

just in case there are conflicts between different .js files (if that exists) here is the entire set of js files I include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/locale/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("hello!");
        $('.edit').editable('whereever');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

Comment: In general it's bad practice to put script tags in the header of your html. You should put them at the bottom of your HTML <body> tag so that loading them doesn't impede the rendering of the page.

Comment: Something worth trying is putting a console.log("hello!"); in your document ready function to see if that is being called correctly.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: You're loading `jeditable.js`, are you loading `jquery.js`?

Comment: yes I am also loading jquery <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> and yes I definitely intent to put it at the bottom of the page in the end... I am in a testing phase right now

Comment: Please show how you're loading jQuery in the question. The comment formatter messed it up.

Comment: There must be a problem with how you're loading jQuery if the hello isn't showing up.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.